# Can't execute any operations on my sequelize model

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm developing a simple project using sequelize + mysql + express and I got stuck because of a simple problem: can't execute function like findById and so on using my model.

For the following code, I got "db.usuario.findById(...).exec is not a function" message. I'm a newbie.

This is my model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('usuario', {
    id_Usuario: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(18),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    tipo: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(1),
      allowNull: false
    },
    nome: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false
    },
    matricula: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    telefone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(15),
      allowNull: true
    },
    cpf: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(11),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    senha: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false
    },
    instituicaoEnsino: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'usuario'
  });
};
```

And this is my controller:

```
var db = require('../db');

exports.user_edit_get = function(req, res, next) {

    async.parallel({
        user: function(callback) {
            db.usuario.findById(req.params.id)
              .exec(callback)
        },
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        //Successful, so render
        res.render('usuarioDetalhes', { user } );
    });

}
```

my db.js file:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mydb', 'root', 't3st3@B4NCO00', {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '3306',
  dialect: 'mysql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
});

// Connect all the models/tables in the database to a db object,
//so everything is accessible via one object
const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

//Models/tables
db.usuario = require('./models/usuario.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);

module.exports = db;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to be a mixture of Sequelize and Mongoose, both of which have a method called `findById`:

```
db.usuario.findById(req.params.id)
  .exec(callback)
```

Mongoose uses `exec`, whereas the Sequelize method `findById` will return a Promise. There really isn't any need to use `async.parallel`, you can use `Promise.all` instead (I'm assuming that your real code contains multiple queries, if you really only have 1 then you don't need any of this).

If you were to do this using `async.parallel` it might look something like this:

```
async.parallel({
    user: function(callback) {
        db.usuario.findById(req.params.id).then(
            function(value) {
                callback(null, value);
            },
            function(err) {
                callback(err);
            }
        );
    }
}, ...
```